# Removing Header and Footer from file using a unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I apologize all for being so bad in using unix shell but i would appreciate your help to create a shell that will remove the header and the footer from a file.
In particular:

- the header will be represented by all the row between the string "BEGINHEADER" and "ENDHEADER"
- the footer will be the last row

Here below an example of such file:

```
NA1707202302030356                                                                                                                                                                                                              
BEGINHEADER                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
DATA_REPORTING=D=10                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SEPARATORE=C=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
DATA_CONVERSIONE=D=10                                                                                                                                                                                                             
....                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ENDHEADER
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;                                                                                                                                                                        
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
....
FOOTER
```

I've tried using grep command to retrieve the both row of BEGINHEADER and ENDHEADER but i did not find any way to use this information to remove all the lines between them.

To remove footer i'm currently using:
sed -i '$d' TEST.txt

Comment: Is `FOOTER` an example in your test file, or in the real data is it really always going to be exactly the word `FOOTER`?

Comment: (This is a place, btw, where I'd probably use `awk`).

Comment: If the first part of the data you want is always a date you can do something like `sed/grep "s/^[0-3][0-9]\//" foo.txt`.

Comment: BTW, your data in the question has a lot of whitespace at the ends of the lines. Is that true of your real data too? (It breaks some answers that assume that the whole line might be the exact string `BEGINHEADER` or `ENDHEADER` if the header is actually started by `BEGINHEADER<space><space><space>...`, as is true in the sample in the question right now)

Answer (score 1):

This is a task well-suited to awk.

```
$1 == "BEGINHEADER" { in_header=1; next; }
$1 == "ENDHEADER" { in_header=0; next; }
{
  if (in_header) { next }
  if (NR > 1) {
    print last_line
  }
  last_line=$0
}
```

...which could be shortened to a one-liner simply by removing the newlines:

```bash
awk '$1 == "BEGINHEADER" { in_header=1; next; } $1 == "ENDHEADER" { in_header=0; next; } { if (in_header) { next } if (NR > 1) { print last_line } last_line=$0 }'
```

...emits, given your input:

```
NA1707202302030356
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
....
```

We use the variable `last_line` to store the previous line; by printing one line behind (and not printing anything on the first line, when `last_line` is empty), we thus skip the final line of the file.

Mind, if your real data can't contain whitespace at the ends of lines (as the sample data in the question currently does), I'd use `$0` for comparisons instead of `$1` to compare the lines' full content.

Answer (score 1):

The following might work for you:

```bash
awk '
    $1 == "BEGINHEADER" { skip = 1; next; }
    $1 == "ENDHEADER"   { skip = 0; next; }
    $1 == "FOOTER"      { exit }
    !skip
' file.txt
```

If you prefer to use `sed`:

```bash
sed '/BEGINHEADER/,/ENDHEADER/d;/FOOTER/,$d' file.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure the footer will always be the word `FOOTER`; asked the OP that in a comment on the question, no response received -- but I find it notable that they started with `sed -i '$d'` instead of `grep -v FOOTER`. This is certainly the approach I would have taken if it had been clear that the exact word `FOOTER` is all we needed to match.

Answer (score 1):

If `FOOTER` is a string at the last line

```
$ awk '/BEGINHEADER/,/ENDHEADER/{next} !/FOOTER/{print}' inputfile
NA1707202302030356
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
....
```

Otherwise remove the last line

```
$ awk '/BEGINHEADER/,/ENDHEADER/{next}1' <(head -n -1 inputfile)
NA1707202302030356
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
01/31/2023;01/23/2023;03000986096;
....
```

Or ignore the last line

```
awk '
    /BEGINHEADER/,/ENDHEADER/{next} 
    {a[i++]=$0}
    END{for(i=0; i<length(a)-1; i++) print a[i]}
' inputfile
```

Or

```
$ awk '/BEGINHEADER/,/ENDHEADER/{next} prv{print prv} {prv=$0}' inputfile
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're leaving the `1` outside the quotes?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not really. Changed.